# convertir rango de fechas en secuencia de fechas consecutivas

Tags: r, date

> Tengo una dataframe con dos variables "fecha inicio" y "fecha fin". Quiero convertirlas en una única variable cuyos valores sean la secuencia diaria entre ambas fechas. Sin utilizar bucles
>   dataframe partida

```
sku <- c('a','b')
start <- c(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-23"))
end <- c(as.Date("2018-01-04"), as.Date("2018-02-25"))
value <- 1
df_input <- data.frame(sku,start,end,value)
```

> dataframe salida

```
date1 <- c("2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-03","2018-01-04")
date2 <- c("2018-02-23","2018-02-24","2018-02-25")
value1 <- c("a","a","a","a")
value2 <- c("b","b","b")
df1 <- data.frame(value1,date1)
df2 <- data.frame(value2,date2)
colnames(df1) <- c("value","date")
colnames(df2) <- c("value","date")
df_output <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

Comment: Hola! Cuál es tu pregunta? Qué pasa con este código? ¿Podrías por favor, explicarlo (y poner un título acorde) en español?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución con R base podría ser la siguiente:

```
# generamos un vector con la cantidad de días a expandir cada fila
dias <- (df_input$end - df_input$start) + 1
# expandimos cada fila la cantidad de días de cad intervalo
new_df <- df_input[rep(row.names(df_input), dias), ]
# calculamos la columna date en base al inicio más la secuencia de los días
new_df$date <- with(new_df, start + (sequence(dias)-1))
new_df

    sku      start        end value       date
1     a 2018-01-01 2018-01-04     1 2018-01-01
1.1   a 2018-01-01 2018-01-04     1 2018-01-02
1.2   a 2018-01-01 2018-01-04     1 2018-01-03
1.3   a 2018-01-01 2018-01-04     1 2018-01-04
2     b 2018-02-23 2018-02-25     1 2018-02-23
2.1   b 2018-02-23 2018-02-25     1 2018-02-24
2.2   b 2018-02-23 2018-02-25     1 2018-02-25
```

Answer (score 1):

aqui hay una alternativa:

```
individuos <- as.character(c("Pedro","Luis","Marta"))
inicio <- (c("2020-01-02","2020-01-05","2020-01-03"))
fin <- (c("2020-01-12","2020-01-08","2020-01-10"))

datos <- as.data.frame(cbind(individuos,inicio,fin))


base2=NULL
  for (i in 1:length(individuos)) 

      {

    sec = seq(as.Date(datos$inicio[i], format = '%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date(datos$fin[i], format = '%Y-%m-%d'), by = "1 days")
    ind = rep(datos$individuos[i], length(sec))

    base1 = cbind(as.character(ind), format(sec, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    base2 = as.data.frame(rbind(base2, base1))

  }

base2

      V1         V2
1  Pedro 2020-01-02
2  Pedro 2020-01-03
3  Pedro 2020-01-04
4  Pedro 2020-01-05
5  Pedro 2020-01-06
6  Pedro 2020-01-07
7  Pedro 2020-01-08
8  Pedro 2020-01-09
9  Pedro 2020-01-10
10 Pedro 2020-01-11
11 Pedro 2020-01-12
12  Luis 2020-01-05
13  Luis 2020-01-06
14  Luis 2020-01-07
15  Luis 2020-01-08
16 Marta 2020-01-03
17 Marta 2020-01-04
18 Marta 2020-01-05
19 Marta 2020-01-06
20 Marta 2020-01-07
21 Marta 2020-01-08
22 Marta 2020-01-09
23 Marta 2020-01-10
```

Answer (score 1):

Si queremos generar una secuencia para un vector la mejor alternativa es vectorizar la función `seq.Date`y luego generar un `data.frame` a partir de los nombres.

```
# Vectorizamos la funcion seq.Date
vecSeq <- Vectorize(seq.Date, c("from", "to"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# Generamos una lista con cada una de las secuencias
lista <- vecSeq(from = as.Date(df_input$start), to = as.Date(df_input$end), by = 'days')

# Llamamos a cada lista por el nombre de la columna sku
names(lista) <- df_input$sku


# Generamos el data.frame de salida
df <- data.frame(value = rep(names(lista), sapply(lista, length)),
                 date = do.call('c', lista), row.names = NULL)
```

Si tienes alguna duda lo explico más detalladamente en esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/323578/155884).