# ¿Cómo generar días entre dos fechas con R?

Tags: r, date, bucle-for, bucles, datatable

Tengo un datatable que contiene la siguiente información.
Nombre, fencha de inicio y fecha fin.

```
individuos <- c("Pedro","Luis","Marta")
inicio <- c("2020-01-02","2020-01-05","2020-01-03")
fin <- c("2020-01-12","2020-01-08","2020-01-10")
datos <- data.table(cbind(individuos,inicio,fin))
```

Me gustaría crear una salida de forma que hubiera una fila por cada día que va desde la fecha de inicio hasta la fecha fin por individuo.

```
Pedro 2020-01-03
Pedro 2020-01-04
Pedro 2020-01-05

...
Pedro 2020-01-12
Luis  2020-01-05
Luis  2020-01-06
...
```

He intentado utilizar un for (aunque no me gustan nada) pero no he sido capaz.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Uko, si conviertes las fechas con `as.Date()` y tomas en cuenta los nombres de las variables, tu pregunta esta respondida aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/300040/31764, cualquier cosa me dices, pero creo que perfectamente esta es duplicada de la que te menciono. Saludos.

Comment: Patricio, tienes razón, esta respodida donde me has dicho, he podido resolver el problema.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [convertir rango de fechas en secuencia de fechas consecutivas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299898/convertir-rango-de-fechas-en-secuencia-de-fechas-consecutivas)

Answer (score 1):

Como JRN voy a partir de un data.frame en lugar de un data.table pero funciona igual con data.table:

```
individuos <- c("Pedro","Luis","Marta")
inicio <- c("2020-01-02","2020-01-05","2020-01-03")
fin <- c("2020-01-12","2020-01-08","2020-01-10")

datos <- as.data.frame(cbind(individuos, inicio, fin))
```

Para evitar utilizar un bucle he vectorizado la secuenciación de las fechas:

```
vecSeq <- Vectorize(seq.Date, c("from", "to"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
lista <- vecSeq(from = as.Date(inicio), to = as.Date(fin), by = 'days')
```

A este punto quiero explicar algunas cosas que me han generado problemas:

En un primer lugar intente vectorizar la función `seq` pero no lo permite, por no tener argumentos definidos (`seq(...)`). Por lo que habría que utilizar `seq.default` pero `seq.default` no maneja bien las fechas y produce un error al pasar las fechas a `numeric`, por lo que hay que utilizar `seq.Date`.

Con `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` lo que hacemos es que el output sea una lista en lugar de una matriz, algo imprescindible si tenemos en cuenta que los distintos individuos pueden tener cantidades de fechas distintas.

A cada lista le asignamos como nombre el individuo al que esta asociado:

`names(lista) <- individuos`

Lista tiene esta forma:

```
$Pedro
 [1] "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-04" "2020-01-05" "2020-01-06" "2020-01-07" "2020-01-08" "2020-01-09" "2020-01-10"
 [10] "2020-01-11" "2020-01-12"

$Luis
 [1] "2020-01-05" "2020-01-06" "2020-01-07" "2020-01-08"

$Marta
 [1] "2020-01-03" "2020-01-04" "2020-01-05" "2020-01-06" "2020-01-07" "2020-01-08" "2020-01-09" "2020-01-10"
```

Una vez tenemos las secuencias de fechas solo hay que pasarlas a un data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(individuo = rep(names(lista), sapply(lista, length)),
                 fechas = do.call('c', lista), row.names = NULL)
```

Aquí me he encontrado con otro conflicto, al intentar pasar `lista` de formato lista a un vector para crear la columna de fechas he intentado utilizar `unlist()`, pero otra vez me transformaba las fechas a `numeric` por eso hay que utilizar `do.call('c', lista)`.

El resultado de `df` sería:

```
   individuo     fechas
1      Pedro 2020-01-02
2      Pedro 2020-01-03
3      Pedro 2020-01-04
4      Pedro 2020-01-05
5      Pedro 2020-01-06
6      Pedro 2020-01-07
7      Pedro 2020-01-08
8      Pedro 2020-01-09
9      Pedro 2020-01-10
10     Pedro 2020-01-11
11     Pedro 2020-01-12
12      Luis 2020-01-05
13      Luis 2020-01-06
14      Luis 2020-01-07
15      Luis 2020-01-08
16     Marta 2020-01-03
17     Marta 2020-01-04
18     Marta 2020-01-05
19     Marta 2020-01-06
20     Marta 2020-01-07
21     Marta 2020-01-08
22     Marta 2020-01-09
23     Marta 2020-01-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Pruebe con esta:

```
individuos <- as.character(c("Pedro","Luis","Marta"))
inicio <- (c("2020-01-02","2020-01-05","2020-01-03"))
fin <- (c("2020-01-12","2020-01-08","2020-01-10"))

datos <- as.data.frame(cbind(individuos,inicio,fin))


base2=NULL
  for (i in 1:length(individuos)) 

      {

    sec = seq(as.Date(datos$inicio[i], format = '%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date(datos$fin[i], format = '%Y-%m-%d'), by = "1 days")
    ind = rep(datos$individuos[i], length(sec))

    base1 = cbind(as.character(ind), format(sec, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    base2 = as.data.frame(rbind(base2, base1))

  }
```

base2

```
      V1         V2
1  Pedro 2020-01-02
2  Pedro 2020-01-03
3  Pedro 2020-01-04
4  Pedro 2020-01-05
5  Pedro 2020-01-06
6  Pedro 2020-01-07
7  Pedro 2020-01-08
8  Pedro 2020-01-09
9  Pedro 2020-01-10
10 Pedro 2020-01-11
11 Pedro 2020-01-12
12  Luis 2020-01-05
13  Luis 2020-01-06
14  Luis 2020-01-07
15  Luis 2020-01-08
16 Marta 2020-01-03
17 Marta 2020-01-04
18 Marta 2020-01-05
19 Marta 2020-01-06
20 Marta 2020-01-07
21 Marta 2020-01-08
22 Marta 2020-01-09
23 Marta 2020-01-10
```

Comment: Hola @JRN, revisa esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299898/convertir-rango-de-fechas-en-secuencia-de-fechas-consecutivas que dejé en mi comentario más arriba, por que es prácticamente la misma que esta. Voy a votarla como duplicada, por lo que te sugiero que agregues esta misma buena respuesta a la pregunta que te menciono. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @JRN, gracias por tu solución, valida también.

Comment: Listo, ya esta agregada esta respuesta a la otra pregunta. @PatricioMoracho
Con gusto. Uko

Answer (score 0):

Existe otra manera de hacerlo utilizando la librería de purrr

Primero es importante mencionar que las columnas de inicio y fin son fechas

```
individuos <- c("Pedro","Luis","Marta")
inicio <- c("2020-01-02","2020-01-05","2020-01-03")
fin <- c("2020-01-12","2020-01-08","2020-01-10")
datos <- data.frame(individuos,inicio=as.Date(inicio),fin=as.Date(fin),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Ahora utilizamos la función pmap_dft que nos ayuda aplicar una función sobre un grupo de vectores o listas, y al final regresa un data.frame en caso de tener las mismas dimensiones (mismo numero de columnas) en cada resultado

```
pmap_dfr(list(datos$inicio,datos$fin,datos$individuos),function(x,y,z) {
                                                   data.frame(individuos=rep(z,length(seq.Date(x,y,"days"))),
                                                              fechas=seq.Date(x,y,"days"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)})
```

El resultado obtenido es el siguiente:

```
 individuos     fechas
1       Pedro 2020-01-02
2       Pedro 2020-01-03
3       Pedro 2020-01-04
4       Pedro 2020-01-05
5       Pedro 2020-01-06
6       Pedro 2020-01-07
7       Pedro 2020-01-08
8       Pedro 2020-01-09
9       Pedro 2020-01-10
10      Pedro 2020-01-11
11      Pedro 2020-01-12
12       Luis 2020-01-05
13       Luis 2020-01-06
14       Luis 2020-01-07
15       Luis 2020-01-08
16      Marta 2020-01-03
17      Marta 2020-01-04
18      Marta 2020-01-05
19      Marta 2020-01-06
20      Marta 2020-01-07
21      Marta 2020-01-08
22      Marta 2020-01-09
23      Marta 2020-01-10
```